# How to keep version DRY for both node.js and docker

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

I'm building a set of microservices that are run on Docker and orchestrated with Kubernetes. I'm building the services in Node.js and so for each service I have a `package.json` file that has a version. I'd like to use this version when building my docker images, and to keep the build command simple I'd like to have it be a script in `package.json`. However, I want to keep the version number DRY (i.e. avoid spreading the version number throughout the `package.json` file, or having any other copies). For example, if I have the following package.json, how could I reference the version in the script to avoid repeating it?

```
{
  "name": "sample-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample service",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "docker": "docker build -t prefix/image-name:$version ."
  }
}
```

Obviously, using `$version` in the tag there doesn't work so is there another way? Just in case it makes a difference, I'm using `yarn` rather than `npm`.

Comment: This should work if not then ping here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes First get the version of `package.json`

Then export the version to the variable so you can access it as a `variable`.

Here is your package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample service",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "scripts": {
    "docker": "export version=$(node -e \"console.log(require('./package.json').version)\") || set version=$(node -e \"console.log(require('./package.json').version)\") ; echo version is: $version;  docker build -t prefix/image-name:$version ."  }
}
```

If you run this you will get some thing like

[image]